# Pointer of a union

Tags: c, pointers, struct, union

Consider the union type below.

```
typedef union nodeTypeTag {
    nodeEnum nodeType; 
    ruleNode rule; 
    conNode cond; 
    actNode act; 
    exprNode expr; 
    litNode lit; 
} ASTnode;
```

in which `nodeEnum` is enum and `ruleNode`, `conNode`, `actNode`, `exprNode`, `litNode` are all structure types.

Now, assume that in my main function, I do this:

```
ASTnode * tmp;
tmp = (ASTnode *) malloc(sizeof(ASTnode));
```

and assume that I have another function which takes parameters:
`myfun(conNode * conditions)`
What would happen if I pass `tmp` to this function? Would it give error? Why? Would it do implicitly change type of pointer? I am new to the idea of union types.

Thanks

Comment: Why pass `tmp` to `myfun(conNode * conditions)`, when code could pass `&tmp->cond` and get the type right?

Comment: @chux I guess that would do it. But I am curious about the behaviour of unions in this case

Comment: The issue is not of `union`s, but asking if a pointer to a `struct` is compatible with a pointer to a `union` - which off-hand I think it is not always OK - see C11 §6.2.5 28  GTG

Comment: You'd get errors if you invoked the compiler in conforming mode and configured it to treat all diagnostics as errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer to `ASTnode` (which is `union nodeTypeTag *`) and the pointer to `conNode` (`struct *`) are incompatible. And it is definitely wrong to pass one in stead of the other.

The standard only says that (C11 6.2.5 28):

> All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

But pointers to union types and pointers to structure types do not have the same representation and alignment requirements.

Also relevant here is 6.5.7

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of  the following types:
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,

Attempt to access the object of type `conNode` through a non-compatible type in `myfun` is a violation of the above rule.